# How to run the first three methods with @Test in sequential order and next three methods with @Test in parallel, using TestNG?

Tags: java, selenium, parallel-processing, webdriver, testng

There are 6 methods with @Test (TestNG) annotations. Iwant to run the first three methods with @Test in sequential order and next three methods with @Test in parallel, using TestNG. How can I achieve this?

Below is the code snippet:

```
@Test
public void m1(){

}

@Test
public void m2(){

}

@Test
public void m3(){

}

@Test
public void m4(){

}

@Test
public void m5(){

}

@Test
public void m6(){

}
```

Thanks much in anticipation!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), have a look around, and read through the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). - *UnitTests* must not depend on order of execution. If you are doing *UnitTest* (in contrast to *acceptance tests* executed with *TestNG*) You should redesign your tests.

Comment: Is m4/5/6 dependent of m1/2 or 3 method?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, to preserve order you can use priority:

```
@Test (priority=1)
public void m1(){

}

@Test (priority=2)
public void m2(){

}

@Test (priority=3)
public void m3(){

}
```

Notice that you don't need to set priority for the rest of the methods (4-6) as you want to run them in parallel. Here is your xml in order to run this:

```
!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd" >

<suite name="Regression" parallel="methods" thread-count="3">

 <test name="smokeTest">    
    <classes>   
    <class name="regression.sequentialParallelExecution"/>  
    </classes>
 </test>   

</suite>
```

Things worth noticing for the XML above:

1. You are choosing to execute in parallel methods (you can also opt for tests or instances)
2. Thread-count is 3 as you want 3 methods to be executed in parallel
3. The first 3 methods will run one after the other sequentially (even when in parallel mode they still preserve the priority order)

*PS. if you want method 2 not to be executed if method 1 fails then you can use depends on methods as following:*

```
@Test (priority=1)
public void m1(){

}

@Test (priority=2, dependsOnMethods="m1")
public void m2(){

}
```

Best of luck!

**Note for Julian who edited my post. First of all thank you very much I was not aware that dependsOnMethods prevails priority. I have to admit, I am a bit confused though. I have been using successfully priorities and dependsOnMethods together getting the desired results. In order to double check my findings I found this post [priorities and dependsOnMethods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24423092/testng-not-running-in-priority-order-when-dependsonmethods-is-specified). I've literally copy-pasted the code posted by OP and got the *'expected result'* straight away with no modifications. I would be glad if could explain it further. Cheers!**

Comment: Many thanks! Works like a charm. Let me know what you think about having dependsOnMethods, instead of having priority. Like below:
`code`
@Test(dependsOnMethods={"m4"})
 public void m1() {

 }

 @Test(dependsOnMethods={"m1"})
 public void m2() {

 }

 @Test(dependsOnMethods={"m2"})
 public void m3() {

 }
`code`
Where m4(), m5() and m6() are running in parallel.

Comment: Glad I as of some help! I think you can manipulate both in order to suit your needs. I.e. you can force all of your methods to drop like domino (one depending on the next one); or in some cases you might want more than one methods to depend on the same method. For example, don't look for the inbox element if user prior failed to login (dependOnMethods=login). Personally I use depends on methods to quickly skip the future tests if something core fails. In some rare occasions, I would base more than 1 method on the same target in order to regulate flow. (i.e. dependsOnMethods="dbConnection")