# How to execute multiple test cases using testNG

Tags: selenium, testng

I want to understand how do we execute multiple test cases using testNg. Suppose my web application consists of 10 pages.Then how do we execute the below test cases.

1) 1st TC- Traversing or navigating to page 1,2,3,4,5&6.

2) 2nd TC- Traversing or navigating to page 1,2,3,8,9&10.

3) 3rd TC- Traversing or navigating to page 1,2,6,7,8.

all pages have corresponding priorities. Page 1 has priority 1, Page 2 has priority 2 etc.

Is it that we need to call related methods(methods defined in each page.) in each @Test annotations.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have multiple pages then you can have Page object class for each web page. that class can have multiple methods which implemented as operation that could be performed on that page and may return object of next page it is navigating to. Using such objects of Page object classes and their methods, you can design your test method that will be considered as Test case.

E.g.
- for Login page, define Login.java with all the required elements on the page and define method as below

```
public Homepage loginAction(String Username, String Password){
      // write code to perform login opeartion
      // it returns Homepage object that you can store in Homepage type variable and you can call other operations of Homepage on that object.
}
```

Once, you have all the Page object classes are ready to consume, you can write test cases by calling tat methods.

E.g.:

```
@Test
public void TestCaseOne(){
      Login loginpage = new Login();
      Homepage homepage = loginpage.loginAction("ABC","XYZ");
      homepage.selectAcc(1);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems like you have one `@Test`  annotated method for each page. If they can traverse correctly logically as you have mentioned, then to run them for your test cases , I would remove priorities from TC's and use this xml with `preserve-order="true"` , so they run in same order. You can add more TC to below in same manner.  Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58027931/testng-test-case-is-ignored/58103392#58103392)

Below xml will call methods in that order , you need to make sure they can go to your pages correctly

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="yourSuiteName" >

    <test name="1stTC" preserve-order="true">

        <classes>  
         <class name="yourPackage.YourClass" >
               <methods> 
                  <include name="method1" />
                  <include name="method2" /> 
                  <include name="method3" />
                  <include name="method4" />
                   <include name="method5" />
                  <include name="method6" />
               </methods> 
          </class>
       <classes> 
      </test>

<test name="2ndTC" preserve-order="true"> 
       <classes>         
           <class name="yourPackage.YourClass">
               <methods> 
                  <include name="method1" />
                  <include name="method2" /> 
                  <include name="method3" />
                  <include name="method8" /> 
                  <include name="method9" />
                  <include name="method10" />
               </methods>
          </class>
        </classes>
    </test>
</suite>
```