# dependsOnMehtods order execution not working

Tags: java, selenium, testng

I am executing below tests in testng and using dependsOnMehtods, what i understood from this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24423092/testng-not-running-in-priority-order-when-dependsonmethods-is-specified) is-

> Execute all independent methods (methods without @dependsOnMethods
> annotation)

but in my case-why Test1 not executing first since it does not have dependsOnMethods

```
  @Test
    public void Test1() {
        System.out.println("Test1 Executed");
    }

    @Test(dependsOnMethods = "Test3")
    public void Test2() {
        System.out.println("Test2 Executed");
    }

    @Test
    public void Test3() {
        System.out.println("Test3 Executed");
    }
    @Test
    public void Test4() {
        System.out.println("Test4 Executed");
    }
```

the order i am getting is-

```
Test3 Executed
Test1 Executed
Test4 Executed
Test2 Executed
```

Comment: as per my knowledge it will first try to execute all the dependent methods first

Answer (score 0):

you can keep the order by adding the order in testng.xml

```
<suite>
<test name="TEST_NAME">
        <classes>
            <class name="com.test.TEST_CLASS_NAME" >
                <methods>
                    <include name="Test1"></include>
                    <include name="Test2"></include>
                    <include name="Test3"></include>
                    <include name="Test4"></include>
                </methods>    
             </class>
        </classes>
 
    </test>
</suite>
```

if this doesn't fulfill your request you can create a Listener event here is a nice [explanation](http://beust.com/weblog/2008/03/29/test-method-priorities-in-testng/)

Answer (score 0):

**All testNG tests has default priority 0**

If you do not set priority, then test methods with annotation dependsOnMethods will take precedense, but if you want to control the order then annotation priority will work.

About annotation priority:
If you navigate into declaration/definition of priority (ctrl + 'left click' on the word priorty in you IDE) for testNG you will find the following in interface org.testng.annotations.Test:

```
/**
 * The scheduling priority. Lower priorities will be scheduled first.
 */
int priority() default 0;
```

So if you want to use the annotation **priority** and order the test by the annotation then keep in mind **the lower number the higher the priority**.

In your case it would look like this:

```
@Test(priority = -4)
public void Test1() {
    System.out.println("Test1 Executed");
}

@Test(priority = -3, dependsOnMethods = "Test3")
public void Test2() {
    System.out.println("Test2 Executed");
}

@Test(priority = -2)
public void Test3() {
    System.out.println("Test3 Executed");
}

@Test(priority = -1)
public void Test4() {
    System.out.println("Test4 Executed");
}
```

You will get the following order, and note that Test3 goes before Test2 due to annotation dependsOnMethods:

```
Test1 Executed
Test3 Executed
Test2 Executed
Test4 Executed
```

Note that are many other ways to solve the priority. Here we demonstrate the impact of the default priority. If the negative values does not feels intuitive then you can pass your own values with constants holding the negative values and so on.